# Accessing Radio/Checkbox button selection in Django form post request

Tags: python, django, checkbox, webforms, radio-button

I have a webpage form in django. I have some radio button on my webpage. After user selects the radio button and on submit I need to know which radio button was selected in my views. 
I tried using following code:
Html Template:

```
<form action= "{% url 'rec:opt' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {%  for name in features %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ name }}</td>
        <td>

            <input type="checkbox" name="is_obj" id={{ name }} + "_is_obj" > <br>
        </td>
        <td>
            Lower Limit <input type="text" name="ll" id={{ name }} + "_ll">
            Upper Limit <input type="text" name="ul" id={{ name }} + "_ul">
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

View.py

```
def opt(request):
    print(request.POST['is_obj']) #'on'
```

The request.POST only returns 'on' and doesn't say which radio/check box was selected.
Also the getlist returns following

```
request.POST.getlist['is_obj'] # ['on']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `value` attribute to your checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_obj" id={{ name }} + "_is_obj" value="{{ name|add:'_is_obj' }}">
```

If the value attribute was omitted, the default value for the checkbox is `on`.

Note you can use [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter for string concatination. But be careful strings that can be coerced to integers will be summed, not concatenated.